# Is there a way to align a specfic boostrap nav element in the center?

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-5

So, i am working on a bootstrap navbar for one of my AI projects that i have been working on, but i am encountering a issue with my navbar. I am aware that i am able to center the entire nav with bootstrap 5 in the center, but i am clueless on how to center a specific bootstrap

element in the middle of the navbar.

I tried googling some solutions on how to approach this problem, but i might be wrong on this, but i didn't really get much input on how to effectively solve this problem.

I tried adding mx-auto to the **IntelliQuest(the <a)** which is the one that i am trying to get in the middle, but at the end it just made the situation worse :sob:, anyways does anyone have any input on this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IntelliQuest AI</title>
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <nav class="navbar fontRobot navbar-expand-lg bg-body-transparent">
        <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-item-center" href="#">IntelliQuest</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/ai">AI</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="/admin" aria-disabled="true">Admin</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="centered-text flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p class="solution-text">the solution to school work.</p>
        <p class="TechYear">2024 Tech Fair Project</p>
        <video id="cameraView" style="width: 100%; max-width: 640px;" playsinline autoplay></video>
        <button id="takePictureBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Take Picture</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const cameraView = document.getElementById('cameraView');
            const takePictureBtn = document.getElementById('takePictureBtn');

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    cameraView.srcObject = stream;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);
                });

            takePictureBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
                context.drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                // Get the base64-encoded image data without metadata
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',')[1];

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/image',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'imageData': imgData }),
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);  // Log the response from the server
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });

                const tracks = cameraView.srcObject.getTracks();
                tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
                cameraView.srcObject = null;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap utility class `d-flex` with `align-item-center` to center the item vertically.

Example: `<div class='container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>`

Comment: I just edited my code, and as you can see it doesnt really work. And i am trying to center in the middle the IntelliQuest <a> tag